# Intel Server Unavailable after executing the code

Tags: pandas, intel, intel-oneapi, modin

I am on intel dev cloud and using Intel OneAPI. This is my code till now:

```
# first block of jupyter notebook
import modin.pandas as pd

# second block of jupyter notebook
df = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset.csv')
df.head()
```

```
# output of second block

UserWarning: Ray execution environment not yet initialized. Initializing...
To remove this warning, run the following python code before doing dataframe operations:

    import ray
    ray.init()

2023-09-01 12:00:16,471 INFO worker.py:1636 -- Started a local Ray instance.
```

The first block is running properly but, when I am reading my dataset, it is giving me this warning and server unavailable error.

[image]

If I use `import pandas as pd`, the code is running fine, but `modin.pandas` is not working. My dataset is ~ 1 GB csv file. Why is this happening???

**How to Reproduce this?**

- Step 1 - https://devcloud.intel.com/oneapi/
- Step 2 - click on Getting
  Started tab.
- Step 3 - Go down and Click on launch JupyterLab. (It is
  like Google Colab or Kaggle Notebooks)
- Step 4 - Create ipynb and use
  wget to download this data.
- Data - !wget
  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/datasetab75fb3.zip

**System Information**

- OS - Linux 90-Ubuntu 5.4.0-80-generic
- CPU - Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6128 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- RAM - 188 GB

Comment: It looks like the jupyter server might be crashing. That could happen if Modin is using too much memory. Are you able to share the CSV, or a different CSV that we can use to reproduce the error? 

Also, what is the environment you are working in? Which operating system and version? Which CPU, with how many cores? How much RAM is available? Any of these could affect Modin's performance.

Comment: @MaheshVashishtha I have added system information and how to replicate section.

Comment: @Adrash Wase I have filed a modin issue for your question: https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/6539

Comment: Here's a solution I got from intel forum. But it is not working for me - https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Data-Analytics/Intel-Server-Unavailable-after-executing-this-code/m-p/1521559/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExNOUNNQ0VZUkQ5MlpPfDE1MjE1NTl8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M970

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check if you have installed modin properly. If you are unsure, try to reinstall the relevant modin dependencies etc.

```
pip install “modin[all]” # dependencies + modin execution engines
```

Step 2: import modin.pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv') #Please avoid placing your .csv file under a folder.
```

Let's see what will happen.

Reference:
The pandas library offers user-friendly data structures, including DataFrames, for data analysis. However, it may perform slowly with extensive datasets (e.g., 100 GB or 1 TB) since it wasn't optimized for such large volumes. Fortunately, the Modin library addresses this by allowing you to scale pandas workflows with just one code change.

Comment: Getting same "server unavailable" again after running this code.

Comment: Did you try the step 1 first?

Answer (score -1):

Installing Ray 2.6.1 by running

```
pip uninstall ray
pip install ray==2.6.1
```

and then re-exporting the ipykernel to run the notebook which has

```
import ray
ray.shutdown()
ray.init(_memory=16000 * 1024 * 1024, object_store_memory=500 * 1024 * 1024,_driver_object_store_memory=500 * 1024 * 1024)
```

as first block of the notebook and then desired code in the next block

```
import modin.pandas as pd

# third block of jupyter notebook
df = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset.csv')
df.head()
```

should help to avoid the issue

You can also check [Intel DevCloud support](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Data-Analytics/Intel-Server-Unavailable-after-executing-this-code/m-p/1531256/highlight/true#M987) for the discussion

Comment: You could make this a valid Stack Overflow answer by copy/pasting the working code and version number it worked for you with.  (But not the part that says "can you please try this way?".  Keep the link to the support page, and write something like "if that doesn't work for you, follow up on the devcloud support page" and make that a link.)  The goal is that future readers with the same problem will see a helpful answer directly here on Stack Overflow where they found this question, even if Intel reorganizes their web site yet again and breaks that link, but sending the OP there now is ok IMO.

Comment: See also recent meta.SO discussion on a related topic: [Is it forbidden to suggest to create an GitHub issue/discussion for other problems?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426607) .  This is slightly different since a support request already exists for this problem (and in fact has *already* been linked in comments here by the OP).  So posting a link to it as an answer seems premature as well as link-only, when the OP hasn't confirmed there that the proposed fixes work for them.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35095828)